# Rails ransack search other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am trying to use Ransack with the following example:

**User Model**

```
has_many :books
has_one :profile
```

**Profile Model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Book Model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

User's profile has a field called `name`. In `books/index.html.erb`, there is a table with a users `name` column:

**books/index.html.erb**

`<td><%= book.user.profile.name %></td>`

How can I search the books through the User profile's name?

Comment: you can search  on Profile model first then after then when object searched then you can find it's respective books like profile = Profile.search then  books =[] ; profile.map{|obj| books << obj.books}

Comment: @TusharPal Thank you for your reply. Could you write it in a Answer with Markdown format. So I will accepted when I checked it.

Comment: Thanks i have done it

Answer (score 0):

**Search on Profile model first then after then when object searched then you can find it's respective books like**

```
profile = Profile.search 
@books =[]
profile.map{|obj| @books << obj.books}
```

Above is the way where you can achieve it.

Comment: In the `index` action, there is `@books = Book.all`. How to change `books = []` to something likes `@books`. Thank you.

Comment: Edit the changes

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem before, my understanding ransack can only search direct relation, and cannot use Has Many Through, for now I merge ransack search with joins command,

for your case below is sample code for profile.rb

```
scope :joins_user, lambda { |profile_name|
  joins(user: :book).select('profiles.*','users.*','books.*').
  where("profiles.name = ? ", profile_name)
}
```

below is sample in controller to merge ransack search with "manual search"

```
@search =  Profile.all.join_user(params[:profile_name]).search(params[:q])
```

- Profile.all = return all profile
- join_user(params[:profile_name] will filter only the profile based on params[:profile_name]
- search(params[:q]) this will merge additional ransack search in case you have more than one filter, you can remove this if you just have one filter